# Allowing users to use the same email

Tags: 7, emails

I am working on a system that will be used at least partially by students some of which will likely be grade schoolers.  The old system that we are replacing with a Drupal site would allow mass creation of user accounts all with the same email address.  They did this so that the teacher could just use her email for all of the students and if they needed a password reset the info would just get sent to the teacher.  Also, many very young students do not have their own email accounts.

I need import these accounts into my Drupal site but I am going to have trouble because Drupal 7 does not allow different accounts with the same email.  After a quick Google search I did not find much that was to promising, I found a dirty hack for Drupal 5 but nothing that seemed like it might work with Drupal 7.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [Shared Email](http://drupal.org/project/sharedemail) module.

> The shared email module allows multiple users to use the same email address for different accounts. The module works for both registration and account updates.

Users using that module could also be interested in the Shared Email Password Reset module.

> This module will have users reset their password based on both email and user name, there are some cases where this module can help when using the Shared Email module or when there is a requirement that passwords should be reset only if email and username matches.

Both the modules have a Drupal 8 version, and they are declared compatible with Drupal 9.